# conditional or unconditional probability in the calculation of LGD

Tags: risk-management

lifetime LGD is calculated by the way of a term structure of PD. But this PD at the end are calculated using conditional or unconditional PD? I have found a Lot of different And confusing  definition about that. If conditional PD  are used the  PD tend To decrease. While, I guess, it should decrease due that the Client has been a good payer.